# Variational Autoencoder is just outputting the average of the training set

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, autoencoder

I tried to code a Variational Autoencoder in Tensorflow. But the problem is that after training the Autoencoder is just outputting something that seems like the average of the Training data.
Here's my Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
from os import getcwd

learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
data_len = 50000
training_data = []

for filename in tqdm(glob('D:/AI/Celeba/*.jpg')[0:data_len],desc='loading images'):
    im = scipy.misc.imread(filename)
    im = scipy.misc.imresize(im,(128,128))
    im = im/255
    training_data.append(im)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,128,128,3))
latent_space = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,32))

def encoder(x):
    layer1_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(x,32,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer1_pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer1_conv,2,1,padding='same')
    layer2_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer1_pool,16,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer2_pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer2_conv,2,1,padding='same')
    layer3_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer2_pool,8,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer3_pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer3_conv,2,1,padding='same')
    layer4_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer3_pool,4,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer4_pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer4_conv,2,1,padding='same')
    layer5_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer4_pool,2,3,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer5_pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer5_conv,2,1,padding='same')
    layer7 = tf.layers.flatten(layer5_pool)
    layer8 = tf.layers.dense(layer7,32,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    return layer8

def sampling(x):
    mean = tf.layers.dense(x,32)
    std = tf.layers.dense(x,32)
    eps = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(std))
    z = mean + tf.exp(std/2)*eps
    return z, mean, std

def decoder(x):
    layer1 = tf.layers.dense(x,32,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    layer2 = tf.reshape(layer1,shape=(-1,4,4,2))
    layer3_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer2,2,3,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer3_upsample = tf.image.resize_images(layer3_conv,(8,8))
    layer4_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer3_upsample,4,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer4_upsample = tf.image.resize_images(layer4_conv,(16,16))
    layer5_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer4_upsample,8,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer5_upsample = tf.image.resize_images(layer5_conv,(32,32))
    layer6_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer5_upsample,16,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer6_upsample = tf.image.resize_images(layer6_conv,(64,64))
    layer7_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(layer6_upsample,32,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer7_upsample = tf.image.resize_images(layer7_conv,(128,128))
    layer8 = tf.layers.conv2d(layer7_upsample,3,5,padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu)
    return layer8

encoding, mean, std = sampling(encoder(x))
decoding = decoder(latent_space)
reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(decoding,x))
latent_loss = tf.reduce_mean(0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(mean) + tf.square(std) - tf.log(tf.square(std)) - 1,1))
loss = reconstruction_loss + latent_loss
train = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    example = np.random.random((1,32))
    i = 0
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print('epoch {0} out of {1}'.format(epoch+1,epochs))
        losses = []
        for sample in tqdm(range(int(len(training_data)/batch_size))):
            batch = training_data[sample*batch_size : sample*batch_size+batch_size]
            latent = sess.run(encoding,feed_dict={x:batch})
            l,_ = sess.run([loss,train],feed_dict={x:batch,latent_space:latent})
            losses.append(l)
            test = sess.run(decoding,feed_dict={latent_space:example})[0]
            scipy.misc.imsave(getcwd()+'/training/{}.png'.format(i),test)
            i += 1
        print('average loss:', sum(losses)/len(losses))
        saver.save(sess,getcwd()+'/saved/model.ckpt')
```

After I train this model it only outputs images that look almost identical to the image I attached below, no matter which image or latent variable I input. Does anybody know why my network is behaving like this and how I could fix it?

[image]

Comment: Hmm...is it possible that your latent space is just too small to encode more nuanced information from your dataset? Cool resulting image though, kind of creepy.

Comment: I changed the size of the latent space to 256 and it didn't make any difference. Should I make it even bigger or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Probably not the latent space size then. I'll try to see if anything pops out at me in the code.

Comment: What happens if you decrease the depth of the network?  And if you increase the number of epochs?  (How big is the dataset?)

Comment: Increasing the number of epochs changes nothing and I don't understand what you mean by decreasing the depth of my Network. My dataset is has 50000 images

Comment: @KayJersch I mean decreasing the number of conv/maxpool layers in the encoder and decoder. See if it learns something different when it has fewer free parameters to optimize.

Comment: I set the number of conv and maxpool layers to 2 conv layers and 2 maxpool layers, and now the output images are just incoherent colors.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my auto encoder. It just learns to average out all the images in the training data.

Comment: I guess the issue is the weighting between the two losses. The reconstruction loss should have a much larger weight, typically, the number of pixels in the image, i.e.: `loss = reconstruction_loss * (128*128) + latent_loss`
or 
`loss = reconstruction_loss + latent_loss / (128*128)`.